# Android Viewpager, button click or any otherthing about Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, background, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

[image: Children of Viewpager]

well you can see at image. buttons not working properly.
And how is this problem occur I dont understand.

I am making a quiz app. 
if user click wrong answer, I want make buttons background color red, else click true answer, button background color will green.

at first page which is user selected from a list, buttons working normal.
after swipe in pages buttons working wrong. always it changes previous page button color.

I think the reason of this is, viewpager dont know which button's color should change after my controling method.

this is my controlling method in viewpager activity:

```
public void click(View v) {

            int c = 0;
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cevap1a:
                c = 1;
                controlanswer(c);
                break;
            case R.id.cevap2b:
                c = 2;
                controlanswer(c);
                break;
            case R.id.cevap3c:
                c = 3;
                controlanswer(c);
                break;
            case R.id.cevap4d:
                c = 4;
                controlanswer(c);
                break;
            case R.id.cevap5e:
                c = 5;
                controlanswer(c);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

    public void controlanswer(int a) {

            int d = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
            int answer = mquestiondatabase.get(d).gettrueanswer();


            if (a == answer) {

                truecolor(a);

            } else {

                wrongcolor(a);
                truecolor(answer);

            }
        }

        public void wrongcolor(int wrong) {
            cevapA = (TextView) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.cevap1a);
            cevapB = (TextView) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.cevap2b);
            cevapC = (TextView) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.cevap3c);
            cevapD = (TextView) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.cevap4d);
            cevapE = (TextView) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.cevap5e);

            switch (wrong) {

            case 1:
                cevapA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_buton_clicked);
                break;
            case 2:
                cevapB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_buton_clicked);
                break;
            case 3:
                cevapC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_buton_clicked);
                break;
            case 4:
                cevapD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_buton_clicked);
                break;
            case 5:
                cevapE.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_buton_clicked);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        public void truecolor(int answer) {

            cevapA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cevap1a);
            cevapB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cevap2b);
            cevapC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cevap3c);
            cevapD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cevap4d);
            cevapE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cevap5e);


            AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;
            switch (answer) {

            case 1:

                cevapA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yesilflash);
                rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cevapA.getBackground();
                rocketAnimation.start();
                break;
            case 2:

                cevapB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yesilflash);
                rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cevapB.getBackground();
                rocketAnimation.start();
                break;
            case 3:

                cevapC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yesilflash);
                rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cevapC.getBackground();
                rocketAnimation.start();
                break;
            case 4:
                cevapD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yesilflash);
                rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cevapD.getBackground();
                rocketAnimation.start();
                break;
            case 5:

                cevapE.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yesilflash);
                rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cevapE.getBackground();
                rocketAnimation.start();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Well I combine my old question in a one question

Comment: what's in your logcat? what exact error message do you get?

Comment: well there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have solved.

The main problem is, I had written my code in fragmentactivity. but After that I have suspiced that and put all my codes in fragment.

I think this was a good example of using viewpager.

```
public class newFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ExtraID = "com.num";
public static ViewPager mViewPager;
private static String tag = "sqllist";

int sayfano;
private int c = 0;
int mNum2;
soru msoru;
TextView baslik;
TextView aciklama;
TextView soru;
TextView cevapA;
TextView cevapB;
TextView cevapC;
TextView cevapD;
TextView cevapE;
CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;

public static newFragment newInstance(int num) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    newFragment fragment = new newFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mNum2 = (int) getArguments().getInt("num");
    TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(getActivity());
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    List<soru> mSorus = mDbHelper.getTestData();
    msoru = mSorus.get(mNum2);

    int v = newPagerActivity.sayfano();
    Log.d(tag, "crime fragment on create mnum= " + v + "v = " + v);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);

    aciklama = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.aciklama);
    soru = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.soru);
    cevapA = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cevap1a);
    cevapB = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cevap2b);
    cevapC = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cevap3c);
    cevapD = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cevap4d);
    cevapE = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cevap5e);
    baslik = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.baslik);

    try {
        baslik.setText(msoru.getmId() + ". Soru");
        aciklama.setText(msoru.getmTitle().toString());
        soru.setText(msoru.getmSoru().toString());
        cevapA.setText("A) " + msoru.getmCevap1().toString());
        cevapB.setText("B) " + msoru.getmCevap2().toString());
        cevapC.setText("C) " + msoru.getmCevap3().toString());
        cevapD.setText("D) " + msoru.getmCevap4().toString());
        cevapE.setText("E) " + msoru.getmCevap5().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(tag, "bir kısım kendini bilmez soru kısımcıkları kaybolmuş");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    cevapA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            c = 0;
            cevapanahtari(c);
        }
    });

    cevapB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            c = 1;
            cevapanahtari(c);
        }
    });
    cevapC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            c = 2;
            cevapanahtari(c);
        }
    });
    cevapD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            c = 3;
            cevapanahtari(c);
        }
    });
    cevapE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            c = 4;
            cevapanahtari(c);
        }
    });

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null)
            getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    return v;

}

public void cevapanahtari(int a) {

    int d = newPagerActivity.getViewPager();
    int cevap = msoru.getCevapanahtari();


    if (a == cevap) {
        Log.d(tag, "cevapanahtarı if");
        renkdogru(a);

    } else {
        Log.d(tag, "cevapanahtarı else");
        renkyanlis(a);
        renkdogru(cevap);

    }
}

public void renkyanlis(int yanlis) {
    Log.d(tag, "renkyanlis" + yanlis);
    switch (yanlis) {

    case 1:
        cevapA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_buton_clicked);
        break;
    case 2:
        cevapB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_buton_clicked);
        break;
    case 3:
        cevapC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_buton_clicked);
        break;
    case 4:
        cevapD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_buton_clicked);
        break;
    case 5:
        cevapE.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_buton_clicked);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

public void renkdogru(int tiklanancevap) {

    AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;
    switch (tiklanancevap) {

    case 1:
        Log.d(tag, "rendogru case 1");
        cevapA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yesilflash);
        rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cevapA.getBackground();
        rocketAnimation.start();
        break;
    case 2:
        cevapB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yesilflash);
        rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cevapB.getBackground();
        rocketAnimation.start();
        break;
    case 3:
        cevapC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yesilflash);
        rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cevapC.getBackground();
        rocketAnimation.start();
        break;
    case 4:
        cevapD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yesilflash);
        rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cevapD.getBackground();
        rocketAnimation.start();
        break;
    case 5:
        cevapE.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yesilflash);
        rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cevapE.getBackground();
        rocketAnimation.start();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

On the otherhand this my new fragment activity

```
public class newPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
public static ViewPager mViewPager;
private int sorusirasi;
private List<soru> mSorus;
final String tag = "anahtar";
soru mSoruchec;
public static int c=1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);
    TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    mSorus = mDbHelper.getTestData();

    Log.d(tag, "fragment activit yaratıldı");


    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mSorus.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int sorusirasi) {

            return newFragment.newInstance(sorusirasi);
        }
    });

    sorusirasi = getIntent().getIntExtra("num", 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < mSorus.size(); i++) {
        if (mSorus.get(i).getmId() == sorusirasi) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
public static int sayfano(){

    return c;

}

public static int getViewPager() {
       return mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    }
```

}